# Sorting dictionary by value and lexicographical

Tags: python, sorting

I have a dictionary : {'a':10,'b':20,'c':5,'d':5,'e':5} and want to get that

```
    b 20
    a 10
    c 5
    d 5
    e 5
```

sorting by value and if i have a equality by value - it must be sorting lexicographically.

Note: using python 2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To match the actual output you want you have to use two keys to sort negating the int value with `-`:

```
d = {'a':10,'b':20,'c':5,'d':5,'e':5}

for k,v in sorted(d.items(),key=lambda x:(-x[1],x[0])):
    print("{} {}".format(k,v))
```

Output:

```
b 20
a 10
c 5
d 5
e 5
```

Comment: Or you don't have to use `ord` at all if you just make the number negative

Answer (score 3):

You can create a list of sorted tuples in this manner, but note that dictionaries themselves are unordered, so you cannot sort the dictionary itself (unless you use something like [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

```
>>> d = {'a':10,'b':20,'c':5,'d':5,'e':5}
>>> list(sorted(d.items(), key = lambda i : (i[1],i[0]), reverse = True))
[('b', 20), ('a', 10), ('e', 5), ('d', 5), ('c', 5)]
```

Answer (score 1):

In most cases you just need to print the data sorted, in which case it's simply:

```
>>> for x in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0])):
        print x[0], x[1]


b 20
a 10
c 5
d 5
e 5
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    from collections import OrderedDict
    print OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))


    OrderedDict([('a', 10), ('b', 20), ('c', 5), ('d', 5), ('e', 5)])
```

Comment: This is to get the output in the format you want, however I agree with @Cyber